# how to set boolean attribute in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, checkbox, ejs, checked

In ejs file i cannot get the checkbox's value when i use **checked** attribute. If i remove checked i can get the value.

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <form action="/delete" method="post">
      <div class="item">   
          <input type="checkbox" checked value="<%=item._id%>" name="modified" onchange="this.form.submit()" >  
        <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
      </div>
    </form>
<% }) %>


"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.1"
  }
```

*I first asked my question as follows, because I thought that the error was how I set a boolean attribute, but actually the error was the boolean attribute itself. For this reason, I changed my question as above. But since helpful friends answered my first question, I didn't want to delete the first version of the question.*

*Initial version of my question:*

I want to set checked attribute of checkbox conditionally. When i don't use checked attribute, i can get the value attribute in the post method correctly. However when i add checked attribute to checkbox,  the code  sets the checked property but I cannot get the value attribute of the checkbox (it becomes undefined in post method). Please can someone explain to me.

When i use completed variable as checked attribute, i cannot get the value of checkbox.

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
          <form action="/delete" method="post">
            <div class="item">  
              <% let completed = item.done ? "checked" : "" %>
              <input type="checkbox"  value="<%=item._id%>" <%=completed%> name="modified" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
              <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
            </div>
          </form>
<% }) %>
```

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
app.get("/" , (req , res) => {
    res.render("index" , {check : 'checked'})
})
```

```js
<input type="checkbox" name="Test" <%- check %> >
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking your precious time to try and help @Iman, I followed your advice, but the error and the result did not change. I think there is a problem with boolean attribute in ejs. I got the same error even when I patched the checked attribute manually.

Comment: @SpecType
I'm really sorry dude i don't have any other ideas